# Batch File: Copying files to an unknown folder name

Tags: batch-file, variables, xcopy

I looked through the search but hadn't found a solution for this specific issue.

I'm working with batch files and have an issue where I need to backup a directory into one that will have a name that will differ between computers.  The destination folder would be C:\XXXXXX-random.  The X's being 6 numbers and the characters behind it are unknown.

Is there a method I could utilize where the batch file will recognize the file by the "XXXXXX-" format and spit it into a variable (%BackupDirName% for example)?  From here I can utilize the following.

```
xcopy %workdrive%:\DIR_TO_BACKUP "c:\%BackupDirName%"  /e /i /h /y
```

I have been playing around with findstr but can't seem to get any useful results.

I'll admit that this is reaching beyond my scope of abilities.

Comment: How about a `for` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"

FOR /d %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\??????-*") DO (
 FOR /f "delims=-" %%b IN ("%%~nxa") DO (
  SET /a num=1%%b 2>nul
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO %%b %%a
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

Scan the directory for directorynames which fit the pattern *6_characters*-*something* to `%%a` then with each matching name, extract the part before the `-` to `%%b` by using only the leafname.

Assign the result, preceded by a `1` to a dummy variable, suppressing error messages. If the assignment generates an errorlevel of 0, then the selected leaf in `%%b` (which has a fullname of `%%a`) is 6-numeric.

I'd suggest you append ? `%%~pnxa\` to `%backupdirname%` to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: Oh, Magoo, you've done it again.  This worked perfectly.  Thank you.